# Яким чином варто виділяти слова, що є предметом обговорення?

Tags: discussion

[Аналог обговорення](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/193496) на English SE.

Приклади виділення, які вже присутні на Ukrainian SE:

- Синоніми слова "сир" у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова «сир» у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова `сир` у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова “сир” у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова ‘сир’ у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова **сир** у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова *сир* у побутовому спілкуванні
- Синоніми слова <kbd>сир</kbd> у побутовому спілкуванні <sub>(радше як жарт)</sub>

Звичайно, це лише питання стилю. Кожен обирає, що йому до вподоби. Але по собі знаю, що для новачка дуже важливо *не* задаватися такими питаннями на початку, зосереджуючися на питанні/відповіді, а не його оформленні.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моєму, це має вирішувати кожен для себе індивідуально.

---

### <s>Спеціальне оформлення за призначенням</s> (немає)

Було б добре, якби Stack Exchange пропонував спеціальне оформлення для **внутрішньорядкових цитат**. По аналогії з тим, як він зараз виділяє:

- Абзацні цитати:

  > сир
- Абзацний програмний код:

  ```
  сир
  ```
- Внутрішньорядковий програмний код: `сир`.
- Внутрішньорядкові гарячі клавіші: <kbd>сир</kbd>.

Я маю на увазі не те, щоб він виділяв *схоже*, а те, щоб внутрішньорядкові цитати можна було виділяти *спеціальним* засобом, не звертаючись до універсальних засобів пунктуації (лапки, двокрапки, тире) та форматування (напівжирний, курсив, підкреслення). Аналогічно до того, як зараз програмний код всередині рядка можна виділяти, не звертаючись до універсальних засобів пунктуації та форматування.

Оскільки, очевидно, універсальні засоби на те й універсальні, що вони використовуються не лише для внутрішньорядкових цитат. Бо зараз іноді доводиться обирати спосіб оформлення внутрішньорядкових цитат окремо для кожного тексту, орієнтуючись на частоту вживання універсальних засобів в ньому з іншою метою (*пам'ятайте*, що «сир» — іменник; в «Енеїді» слово *сир* вжито тричі).

На жаль, такого немає. Дарма що гуманітарні розділи на Stack Exchange існують давно. Мабуть, вплинуло те, що він починав як сайт про програмування.

### Спеціальне оформлення не за призначенням

#### Форматування для програмного коду: `сир`.

Переваги:

- Порівняно легко набирати.
- На мовознавчому сайті рідко доводиться форматувати програмний код; тому багатозначності фактично не виникає — можна вважати цей засіб спеціалізованним для внутрішньорядкових цитат.

Недоліки:

- Моноширинний шрифт:

  - незручно читати;
  - не підходить для типографських нюансів (роман Антоненко-Давидовича, але закон Бойля — Маріотта).
- Не можна застосовувати форматування всередині (с**е**ло, а не с**и**ло).
- Просто не за призначенням (наприклад, хтозна, як це впливатиме на пошукові системи, засоби автоматичного читання для сліпих тощо).

#### Форматування для гарячих клавіш: <kbd>сир</kbd>.

Переваги:

- Не моноширинний.
- Можна застосовувати форматування всередині.
- На мовознавчому сайті рідко доводиться вказувати гарячі клавіші, тому [див. вище].

Недоліки:

- Складно набирати (`<kbd>сир</kbd>`).
- Надто різке виділення.
- Трішки зменшений шрифт (коли добре було б, навпаки, показати деталі: іноземець може не розрізнити, наприклад, і/ї).
- Просто не за призначенням ([див. вище]).
- Хтозна, як його переоформлять через N років (оскільки основне призначення цього HTML-тегу зовсім інше, то можуть орієнтуватися на тих, хто використовує його за призначенням, і зробити оформлення ще гіршим).

### Лапки

Особисто я, врешті-решт, зупинився на лапках. Це *стандартний* засіб оформлення внутрішньорядкових цитат. Хоч, на жаль, вони мають багато інших призначень.

Звісно, краще використовувати «правильні лапки, в тому числі „для другого рівня“» (and “for ‘English’ too”). Але не в кожного вони є на клавіатурі, а в того, в кого є, не завжди вистачає терпіння їх набирати. Тому "прямі лапки" — теж припустимий варіант.

Звісно, можна погратися з застосуванням ‹особливих› 「лапок」, 『що』 《не》 〈вживаються〉 в українській типографіці. Але:

- Те, що вони не вживаються в українській типографіці, часто робить їх ще менш зручними для введення (хіба що для людей, які з власних причин мають ці символи на клавіатурі).
- Якось дивно використовувати на сайті про українську мову неукраїнські лапки (хтось ще вирішить, що такі лапки для нас типові).

### Напівжирний і курсив

Ну, тут все зрозуміло. Якщо напівжирний чи курсив не використовується багато в самому тексті, то можна вживати одне з них для уникнення лапок при коротких внутрішньорядкових цитатах. Також можна вирішити для себе використовувати одне з них для **акцентування уваги**, а інше — для цитування *слів* чи навіть *цілих словосполучень*.

Щодо за і проти використання курсиву для коротких внутрішньорядкових цитат можна сказати:

- В [англійському обговоренні](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/139407) майже прийшли до думки, що використання курсиву в таких випадках — типографський стандарт.
- Написання деяких літер в українській мові сильно варіює в залежності від того, курсив це чи не курсив (наприклад, т — *т*, г — *г*). Це може ускладнювати життя іноземцям, наприклад, *тато* вони можуть на початку сприймати як мамо. Звісно, рано чи пізно людині, що вивчає мову, доведеться це здолати — але, по-моєму, це жорстоко вимагати знати «обидві кирилиці»  *відразу*.

Comment: Лапки — гарний варіянт (а для назви взагалі єдино можливий), але всередині тексту, коли виділень у тексті багато, вони починають занадто "шуміти", тому я більш схиляюся саме до курсиву.